# Key/Value pairs in ComboBox using Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey

I would like to use an enumerator to populate a Combobox with Key/Value pairs. Its important that I hide the key from the user and display the value only. On selecting I would like to capture the key associated with the selected value.

The code looks something similar to this.

```
var
    currentObj: ISuperObject; 
    enum: TSuperEnumerator<IJSONAncestor>;

    while enum.MoveNext do
    begin

        currentObj := enum.Current.AsObject;
        cboUserList.Items.Add(currentObj.S['key'],currentObj.S['value']);

    end;
```

The key **currentObj.S['key']** should be capture on user select of the value 
**currentObj.S['value']** which is visible to the user on the **cboUserList** dropdownlist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't make a GUI control manage your program's data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cross-platform solution would be to use a separate `TStringList` to hold the `key`s, then display the `value`s in the ComboBox and use its item indices to access the `TStringList` items.

```
var
  currentObj: ISuperObject;
  enum: TSuperEnumerator<IJSONAncestor>;

while enum.MoveNext do
begin
  currentObj := enum.Current.AsObject;
  userSL.Add(currentObj.S['key']);
  cboUserList.Items.Add(currentObj.S['value']);
end;
```

```
var
  index: Integer;
  key: string;
begin
  index := cboUserList.ItemIndex;
  key := userSL[index];
 ... 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your key in class, e.g.

```
type
  TKey = class
    S: string;
    constructor Create(const AStr: string);
  end;

constructor TKey.Create(const AStr: string);
begin
  S := AStr;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('value', TKey.Create('key'));
end;
```

And then access it as

```
procedure TForm2.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := (ComboBox1.Items.Objects[ComboBox1.ItemIndex] as TKey).S;
end;
```

just make sure to destroy these objects later

Comment: I would avoid using visual components as part of the business logic.